# Cannot run Docker on Ubuntu (VM)

Tags: docker, ubuntu, virtualbox

I need to run Docker Desktop on Ubuntu through a VM. I have already enabled PAE/NX and VT-x/AMD-V, and virtualization is enabled on my host PC. I have tried installing Docker Desktop in different ways several times, but every time I try to open it, I encounter the same error. A window opens with the following message: "Running VM: running VM and dependencies: running VM: running qemu: qemu: waiting for qemu process: exit status 1." I have uninstalled and reinstalled Ubuntu and Docker multiple times, but without success.

I tried to open Docker-Desktop on my Ubuntu through the Virtual Machine. Every time a window opens with an error so I cannot use Docker-Desktop.

Comment: Docker Desktop itself runs a hidden Linux VM (even on Linux) and running VMs inside VMs can be tricky.  You don't need this VM if you're running on a native Linux host or a Linux VM already; can you use the plain Docker engine, without Docker Desktop?

Comment: I downloaded Docker Engine without any problem, so I guess yeah.